# Show window.alert if response is valid

Tags: javascript, php, alert

Well... I tried this:

```
if ($resp->is_valid) {
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
    print "<script language="javascript">
    window.alert("'Thank you for submitting the track. We will be in touch with you very soon. Click 'Ok' to redirect you to the Homepage.'")
    window.location.href='http://www.xmasterofficial.tk/'
    </script>";
} else {
    echo "Sorry cannot send email as you've failed to provide correct captcha! Try again...";
}
```

I don't know what is the problem. It should create a window.alert if $resp is valid or post a message if not. The window.alert is not showing up.

Comment: You might want to take a look at what's being output in the html

Comment: The displaying of the alert seems like something that should be happening on the client side rather than the server side.

Comment: Did you tried my solution below for your question. is it have any problem still??

Comment: The double quotes inside the double-quoted string looks like a syntax error; you don't need to use the `language=` attribute, just use `<script>`, and drop the double quotes around the `window.alert`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code have some issue in using quotes inside your print statement.Use `echo` instead of `print` while treating with more than one string .and you need to treat quotes separately to work this and this must help you to work your alert option.

```
if ($resp->is_valid) {
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
echo "<script language='javascript'>
window.alert('Thank you for submitting the track. We will be in touch with you very soon. Click Ok to redirect you to the Homepage.')
window.location.href='http://www.xmasterofficial.tk/'
</script>";
} else {
echo "Sorry cannot send email as you have failed to provide correct captcha! Try again...";
}
```

Comment: Ok. Let me check it and I will come with an answer.

Comment: @user1526798  You are always welcome...

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($resp->is_valid) {
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
alert('Thank you for submitting the track. We will be in touch with you very soon. Click Ok to redirect you to the Homepage.');
window.location.href='http://www.xmasterofficial.tk/';
</script>";
} else {
echo "Sorry cannot send email as you have failed to provide correct captcha! Try again...";
}
```